# python ZeroDivisionError thrown by print string command

Tags: python, error-handling

Can anyone suggest a reason why python may throw a ZeroDivisionError when the line in the program throwing the error contains no mathematical instructions other than one that that converts a number to a string:

```
line 194, in print_summary
'mean error, ' + str(mean_error) + '\n' )
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

This piece of code is part of about 10 lines that just writes answers into a file. To check if there is no problem with the value 'mean_error' I put a print statement further up the code which prints:

```
0.374150774766
```

There is no division in the statement so I have no idea why a 'ZeroDivisionError' would be thrown?

Comment: How about presenting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I understand that would desirable but the code is 300 lines long and also calls another 100 line program in order to run. There are sometimes legitimate reasons why an MCVE can't be posted, in this case Its simply not practical. I was simply wondering if anyone had come across this error in these circumstances before. I have cut and pasted directly from the stack so the line causing the error can be seen.

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: So maybe post what's between the two print statements. If people can't replicate it it's very unlikely they can help.

Comment: And you are sure that all of these 400 lines are _crucial_ for your problem to appear? I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks for another helpful comment Rogalski, my point is that when your not sure the source of the error it can be difficult to know which bits to pull together to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got it now. The code above contains a simple function but for some really strange reason the stack only prints the last line  which has nothing to do with the error.

```
 'sensitivity,' + str(tp/(tp+fn)) + '\n' +
 'specificity,' + str(tn/(tn+fp)) + '\n' +
 'mean error, ' + str(mean_error) + '\n' )
```

The lines are all part of a write to file statement but why the stack would only print the last line is not clear as this is NOT the source of the error. If the stack reads the 'write to file' statement as the source of the error then surely it should print the WHOLE statement and not just the very last section?